# Move character from Random Gen to Navezgane Map

Tags: 7-days-to-die

Several times I've moved my character from one Random Gen map to another (during alpha 16.4), and never had any issues. Now I'd like to move my character to a Navezgane map in the same way, but the same process doesn't work, I end up with a scene like in the attached image, with a loop of the starting sound you get when you first login to a fresh game. I can't move, and hitting Tab only shows the inventory menu for a split second.

Anyone successfully accomplish this? I've tried deleting the Region files, the .map file, and every combination of these files.

[image]

Comment: This isn't a supported feature of the game.  Even though it used to work, it isn't designed that way, so there may have been a recent build that broke this "feature".  I would try creating a new character and see if the same steps still works.  This would isolate whether it is your character's data or whether this feature is "broken".

Even the build 16.4 isn't static, because it can still have build revisions (b##)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Finally realized what the issue was here. I was thinking about the only thing that is intrinsically different between random gen and Navezgane was the size of the map. So I ended up being out of bounds for Navezgane. In my Random Gen game, I put a marker at 0,0, and started running for that position. Once I was pretty close, I tried again, and it worked perfectly.

Just wanted to follow up with an answer for posterity, since I know there is a large contingent of people who do this.

Edit:

Going into more detail, basically the boundaries of the Navezgane map are much smaller (the distance you can travel from 0,0 until you hit the radiated zone) than in the random gen maps. Basically the issue I ran into was I was so far outside of the Navezgane map boundary that I was attempting to spawn into an area that was completely out of bounds (not even in the radiated area) of the Navezgane map. Once I moved closer to 0,0 in my previous random gen map, I was able to copy my player file over to a Navezgane map and spawned in near the center of the map.

Comment: Could you please explain the whole process or link an article or something? You know, for posterity ;-)

Comment: I'll update my answer to be more detailed, but there was no link or article that I could find.

Comment: Anecdotal details are fine, since this seems to be a first.  The game is still in Alpha.

Comment: @aalku A lot we do on PC with 7 Days To Die is manually editing save game files or moving folders and files around. There is no standard way at this time to do any of this and worst, a lot of things working for some does not work for others, including editing your perks after an update breaks them or playing modded 7 Days to Die as none of this is officially supported by the vanilla game at this time. Anecdotal details are most of the time the best you can get at this stage.